# multiprocessing django model database

Tags: django, database, multiprocessing

My database in the implementation of this script, the database has lost data, may be more or less, there will be a lot of empty data. thank you
The following list of configuration information:
Sqlite3
Django1.9.8
Python 2.7.6

```
def flush_price():
    logging.error("Sub-process(es) begin.")
    logging.error(int(time.time()))
    key = '2500_wine_info.xlsx'
    lists = import_excel(key)
    lwin11s = []
    for item in lists:
        lwin11s.append(str(item['LWIN11'])[:11])
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(
        is_del=False,
        wine__lwin11__in=lwin11s
    )
    lwins = []
    for contract in contracts:
        lwins.append(str(contract.wine.lwin))
    new_arrs = arr_split(lwins, 50)
    now = conversion_reduce_8_time()
    for index in range(1, 3641):
        date_now = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=index)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=len(new_arrs))
        for new_arr in new_arrs:
            pool.apply_async(request_price, (new_arr, date_now, ))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        break
    logging.error(int(time.time()))
    logging.error("Sub-process(es) done.")


def request_price(new_arr, date_now):
    headers = {
        'CLIENT_KEY': CLIENT_KEY,
        'CLIENT_SECRET': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'ACCEPT': 'application/json',
        'CONTENT-TYPE': 'application/json',
    }
    data = {
        'lwin': new_arr,
        'priceType': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
        "currency": "EUR",
        "priceDate": date_now,
    }
    price_obj = download_page(VINEX_PRICE_API, request_type=1, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    if price_obj.status_code == 200:
        price_obj = price_obj.json()
        if price_obj['httpCode'] == '200':
            lwin_details = price_obj['lwinDetail']
            for lwin_detail in lwin_details:
                # 取得参数
                lwin = lwin_detail['lwin']
                # 取得对象信息
                contract = Contract.objects.filter(is_del=False, wine__lwin=lwin).first()
                wine = contract.wine
                # 设置历史数据更新
                RedWinePriceData.objects.filter(
                    is_del=False,
                    contract=contract,
                    lwin=lwin,
                ).first()
                redwinepricedata = RedWinePriceData()
                redwinepricedata.contract = contract
                redwinepricedata.lwin = lwin
                # 改变数据
                redwinepricedata.priceDate = format_time(detail['priceDate'])
                redwinepricedata.save()
                redwinepricedata.created = add_conversion_8_time(date_now)
                redwinepricedata.save()
```

[Change the database information before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMulT.jpg);
[The changed database information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4wb8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pool.apply_async is also like Python's built-in apply, except that the call returns immediately instead of waiting for the result. An ApplyResult object is returned. You call its get() method to retrieve the result of the function call. The get() method blocks until the function is completed. Thus, pool.apply(func,
 args, kwargs) is equivalent to pool.apply_async(func,
 args, kwargs).get().

Comment: from django.db import connection
connection.close()